# What is the relation of bias in the Bias-Variance trade-off to underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff

In machine learning literature, people often talk about the bias-variance trade-off as well as overfitting and underfitting in the same paragraph. However, in these contexts, bias and variance comes from the decomposition of the loss function (as estimator of the model performance). E.g., for MSE, the loss can be decomposed into Variance + Bias^2 + Noise^2

But since bias is essentially "TargetValue - MeanPrediction", I am wondering how this related to the degree of "underfitting" of a model. In other words, the mean prediction is a constant value. If you have a quadratic function, the "mean prediction" value would always be off from a particular datapoint to a large degree no matter how well you fit that quadratic function, so I am wondering how someone can deduce that a model underfits the dataset by looking at the bias component of a loss function. Wouldn't one have to look at *n* biases (one bias for each target value /data point in the dataset, computed as "TargetValue - MeanPrediction") to draw any conclusions. I am a bit confused how the "bias" component really related to underfitting as I can't see a direct relationship.

Comment: With reference to the first sentence in your second paragraph - that's not what bias is.  The bias of predicting a particular observation $y_i$ by a prediction $\theta_i$ is $\mathbb{E}(y_i - \theta_i)$.  You don't use the "mean prediction", because the mean prediction gets rid of the observation-specific information (denoted by the subscript "$i$".)  You don't use the target value, because that results in the error of the estimate, and we are interested in the bias, not the error.

Comment: Ohhh, I think I misunderstood something when I was reading some literature where they always referred to "average prediction." Since what you say makes a lot of sense, I think they meant average prediction in terms of the a prediction you get when e.g., training a model on different training sets. I.e., then the bias would be this average prediction of all models minus the target. And the variance would be the average prediction for a given data point minus the prediction for that data point for a particular model. I think that would be then also in line with what you said